# Angular get current focused element in angular

Tags: css, angular, web, focus, element

[image]I have a website I am trying to do something like this, when I click on 1, I want the background of this element to change to white and when I click on the second one the background of the first one will disappear and pass to the next one...I have been trying to do this for a long time help me I don't know how to do it

```
<div class="oval">1</div>
<div class="oval">2</div>
<div class="oval">3</div>
```

Comment: With css use the :focus state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we need make "something" exclusive we use one unique variable

```
selectedIndex:number=-1
```

If you want not unselected

```
<div class="oval" [class.selected]="selectedIndex==0"
                  (click)="selectedIndex=0">
    1
</div>
<div class="oval" [class.selected]="selectedIndex==1"
                  (click)="selectedIndex=1">
    2
</div>
<div class="oval" [class.selected]="selectedIndex==2"
                  (click)="selectedIndex=2">
    3
</div>
```

If you want unselected

```
<div class="oval" [class.selected]="selectedIndex==0"
                  (click)="selectedIndex=selectedIndex==0?-1:0">
    1
</div>
<div class="oval" [class.selected]="selectedIndex==1"
                  (click)="selectedIndex=selectedIndex==1?-1:1">
    2
</div>
<div class="oval" [class.selected]="selectedIndex==2"
                  (click)="selectedIndex=selectedIndex==2?-1:2">
    3
</div>
```

NOTE: I use [class.selected], so we use a .css

```
.selected{
   background:red;
}
```

You can use style.background or style.background-color using `(condition)?value:null`, e.g., for the first div

```
[style.background]="selectedIndex==0?'red':null
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kwright02's comment you can do it with css:

```
.myclass:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

But important: The element must be focusable. So a div isn't, a button is as example.

Second way (add a click handler and change the background directly):

```
// HTML
<div (click)="onClick($event)">test</div>

// Code
onClick(event: any) {
    event.target.style["background-color"] = "green";
  }
```

**Note**: This is not the way to go *in Angular*. Here use property binding and bind a style to a condition as example.

Instead of add a click listener to each control you can use Angular's `HostListener` like this:

```
 @HostListener("document:click", ["$event"])
  onAllClick(event: any) {
    event.target.style["background-color"] = "green";
  }
```